# unable to send json dictionary from ajax post call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

i'm working on MVC 4.0 application where i need to send the `AJAX POST` call with JSON Data(`Dictionary`).I'm able to send/pass the normal data, but my problem is i'm unable to send `dictionary` data.

please have a look at the following picture (able to pass normal parameters, ex: `TemporaryId`)

[image]

please have a look at the following picture (not able to pass dictionary from javascript, ex: `_mappedValues`)
[image]

My AJAX call is as below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'api/projects/Advanced',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'TemporaryId': tempId,
            'Name': projectName,
            'InputFileType': 19,
            'Mapping': {
                'Keys': ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'PoleId', 'Description', 'Street'],
                'Values': [values[1],values[2],values[3],values[4],values[5]],                   
                'MappedValues': {
                    'Latitude': selectedMapping[0],
                    'Longitude': selectedMapping[1],
                    'PoleId': selectedMapping[2],
                    'Description': selectedMapping[3],
                    'Street': selectedMapping[4]
                },
                'MandatoryColumns': ['Latitude', 'Longitude'],
                'OptionalColumns': ['PoleId', 'Description', 'Street']
            },
            'IsActualProjectCreatedOrUpdated': false,
            'IsSaveProject': true,
            'ProjectId': null
        },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
        },
```

My Business Logic is as below:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Advanced")]
    public HttpResponseMessage VerifyAndSaveProject([FromBody] ProjectCreationUpdationResult project)
    {
        var result = _projectProcess.ValidateAndSaveProject(project);
    }
```

Class : `ProjectCreationUpdationResult`

```
public class ProjectCreationUpdationResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of project
    /// </summary>
    public int? TemporaryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the project
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of the input file
    /// </summary>
    public int InputFileType { get; set; }  

    public ExcelColumnMapping Mapping { get; set; }

    public bool IsActualProjectCreatedOrUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool IsSaveProject { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Id of project
    /// </summary>
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

class : `ExcelColumnMapping`

```
public class ExcelColumnMapping
{
    private readonly List<string> _keys;
    private readonly List<string> _mandatoryColumns;
    private readonly List<string> _optionalColumns;
    private readonly List<string> _values;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mappedValues;

    //here properties
    ------------------
}
```

Comment: Try 

    `data: JSON.stringify({'temporaryid': ...})`

Comment: thanks for your comment ,i have already tried `JSON.stringify` but now othere parameters are also become `null`

Comment: What if one of your result of the `selectedMapping[n]` return an undefined value? Could you put yourself expected values and see what happens or just pass one property, let say `Latitude`.

Comment: i tried by passing hardcoded values but its not working.